# Blazor WebSocket is stopping from some ip addresses

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, websocket, signalr, blazor

I am working with Blazor and asp.net core. My application can't connect to WebSocket after deploying on iis.
but when I'm using IP changer softwares, it works correctly. this problem doesn't exist in debug or release mode and it's happening after deploying.

The status of application when I'm using my real IP:
[image: Working]

The status of application when ip changer is working:
[image: Error]

Comment: What is "IP changer software"? A VPN? A proxy? What?

Comment: Its a VPN , (I'm in Iran and the server is in Germany)

Comment: It's your VPN then, it doesn't allow websokets

Comment: @aguafrommars but in VPN connected status, it works well

Comment: I didn't get it well then

Comment: You mean, that work on the VPN but not without it ?

Comment: @aguafrommars yes, but its solved now by using https,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem is solved by using https!